# Replace Youtube URL in Yahoo Pipes with /v from watch?v=

Tags: regex, perl, youtube, yahoo-pipes

Currently, a previously answered question left me with this regex in find:

```
^.+(\?|&)v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*$
```

With this as replace

```
hxxp://www.youtube.com/v/$1
```

I want to convert

```
hxxp://www.youtube.com/?watch="YoutubeID"
```

to

```
Youtube.com/v/youtubeID.
```

The current regex fails under this circumstance.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67-YcLickUA
```

As it returns

...v=67, instead of the full VideoID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67-YcLickUA';

$string =~ s(.+watch\?v=([0-9a-zA-Z-]+))(Youtube.com/v/$1);

print "$string\n";
```

This is a very basic replacement, but as I don't know the context etc. you want to use it in it seems good enough for the time being. If you need anything more sophisticated, please let me know.

Comment: @TheBetterJORT In case this answer contains what you were looking for you might want to consider marking it as accepted (by clicking on the tick mark underneath the answer's score) :)

Comment: I used a combo of both regex. Yahoo Pipe is very wierd. Thanks again.